# Binding on Row Selection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

the XAML of my window:

```xml
<ListView Grid.Row="0" Name="files">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="CheckboxTemplate">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Save, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=File, Converter={StaticResource NotEmptyStringConverter}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectFileTemplate">
                <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Select" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                <GridViewColumn Header=" " Width="auto" CellTemplate="{StaticResource CheckboxTemplate}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Datei" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding File}" Width="auto"/>
                <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource SelectFileTemplate}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I want to see the Button (SelectFileTemplate), if a) the Row of the ListView ist Selected and b) if the File-Property is empty

for this i can use a MultiBinding on the Visibility-Property of the Button.
i know how to bind to the file-property, but how to bind to the row-selection?

and how to determine (In Button_Click codebehind) which Select-Button i have pressed? i need a relationship between the ListViewItem and the clicked button of this ListViewItem

Comment: What do you want to do within `Button_Click`?

Comment: In Button_Click a SaveFileDialog is opened, the User selects a file and the path (sfd.FileName) should be written in the File-Property of the ListViewItem - so how to access this ListViewItem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a RelativeSource `DataTrigger` to find the Row and bind to it's `IsSelected` value

Here's an example

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=File}" Value="{x:Null}" />
              <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}" Value="True" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And to get the ListViewItem's data object, you can simply use the Button's DataContext in your Button's Click method, although personally if using the MVVM design pattern I'd rather use the Button's `Command` property to point to a method in the ViewModel and pass the DataConext in through the `CommandParameter`

If you want to get the actual `ListViewItem` UI object from the Button's click method, and not the data object, you have to navigate the Visual Tree to find it. You can use some [VisualTreeHelpers found here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/navigating-wpfs-visual-tree/) to easily find the ListViewItem the Button belongs to

```
var listViewItem = VisualTreeHelpers.FindAncestor<ListViewItem>(myButton);
```

Comment: thank you rachel. your first snippet works perfectly. for solving the second problem i´ve bound my object to the datacontext of the button and now i can access it